# AIR - Add Images From Drag&Drop To Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, drag-and-drop

I'm building a Tile Viewer in Adobe AIR and so far I have implemented the Drag and Drop function that allows the user to load PNG and JPG files.

The function returns a ':File' format, but how can i gram the ':Bitmap' data and place the image in an existing movieclip while looping and make that one tile image repeat in x and y so a preview of a tilemap will shown ?

my thought was to simply add instances of that one file, but i dont know the exact code for that.
( create a Loader, pass the File format to that, and get the BitmapData and place it in place by defining position x and y and also defining width and height. also i want to make instances, to the code doesnt load the image 10 x 10 times )

i would be glad for all helpfull answers.

Edit:

example theory:

( without correct syntax )

```
image = new ImageFromDropBox(); // bitmap or whatever

for( x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for( y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        image.x = tilesize * x;
        image.y = tileSize * y;
        image.width = tileSize;
        image.height = tileSize;
        stage.addChild( image ); // so each of the 100 places images should be just instances of the ONE LOADED IMAGE
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i did, but there was some premission problems, so if i was draging an image into that app, the image could not been overwritten withother programms until the app is closed. i did the app in c# so i dont get much deeper intp this

Answer (score 0):

When working with the `File` class, you can use the `fileInstance.url` parameter to load said file in a loader:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file.url);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
loader.load(urlReq);

function loaded(e:Event):void {
    var bmp:Bitmap = loader.content as Bitmap

    //scale it down and create a scaled down bitmap data for more efficient memory usage
    bmp.width = tileSize;
    bmp.height = tileSize;

    var bData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(tileSize,tileSize); //your new bitmap data
    bData.draw(bmp); //capture the scaled down version of the bitmap

    //if you don't need the original anymore, dispose of it
    bmp.bitmapData.dispose();     

    var image:Bitmap;

    for( var x:int = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        for( var y:int = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            image = new Bitmap(bmp.bData);
            image.x = tilesize * x;
            image.y = tileSize * y;
            image.width = tileSize;
            image.height = tileSize;
            stage.addChild( image );
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, my code is similar, but the point is that i dont know how to place those images ( instances of the one thats beed dragged in the window ) im place by defining position and size.

Comment: Are you saying you want to make the already loaded bitmap the same size and position as the ghosted one that you drag?   Your question and comment isn't very clear as to what you're actually hoping to accomplish (if it's something other than my answer)

Comment: is that really just that simple ? doesn't load the code the picture 100 times from the file ? or are there really instances ?

Comment: it really is that simple, you can re-use the bitmapData in as many bitmap instances as you'd like.  it's a heck of a lot faster than doing 100 seperate loads!

Comment: One thing to caution you on though, is if your original file is huge (3000x3000 pixels lets say), your memory usuage is going to skyrocket and may crash your app loading 100 instances of it.  If your image is huge, you're going to want to scale it down, then create new bitmapData of the scaled down version.

Comment: well thanks for the code , i'll try it in a moment. btw. i dont know any tile based game that uses 3000x3000 px images ;) but yeah i know :D